# How should client of Restful API handle http status 301 redirect upon POST?

Tags: rest, http, error-handling

**Question**

How should a well-designed application handle 301 "moved permanently" redirects upon http POST to restful api?

**Context**

- Our hosted application offers a restful api
- We have a customer extensively who uses our restful api in their own 'on-premise' application [fwiw, installed at dozens of sites-- with no easy way to update]
- We are migrating our application to a new data centers and in the process we will switch them (and others) from 'plain text http' to 'ssl-encrypted https'. [The physical location data center of course is irrelevant, but the new data center has more stringent security rules and thus mandates https]
- Our front end (haproxy/nginx) will send a 301 'Moved Permanently'
- This 301 redirect preserves query parameters but loses post data

I know that "restful api's should be permanent", but, *merde arrive* (that's *shit happens* in French)--Empires crumble, Berlin Wall falls, Oracle buys Sun etc.

**The Problem**

Their application makes HTTP post calls to our restful api. When the front end returns 'http status 301', their application does not 're-post' to the new url, and the update fails.

**Questions**

- How should error handling handle 301's as well as other http statuses? ( pseudocode will suffice)
- Should our 'front end' do something different for '301'?

Comment: Great question. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fulfill your "well-designed" requirement in the sense of "pure RESTfulness", the client should re-send the request to the new URI. A response code of 301 indicate the resource has moved, and cannot be used to fulfill the request, so there's really no fallback position.

If the client attempts to re-post, but loses data, that's a client bug. The "correct" behavior of a client varies by your requirements: it could treat the redirect as a recoverable error case, and repost transparently; it could repost while instructing the user to update the endpoint; or it could fail with an appropriate error message.