# Is there still a use case for HTTP 301 rather than HTTP 308 to indicate that a resource has moved (particularly in a ReST server)?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I am specifying a ReST service. I recently stumbled on this [IETF draft document](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hunt-http-rest-redirect-00.html) which could be interpreted as suggesting that ReST services should always return 308. Note that the document seems to have expired without being superseded (I'm not very clear on the IETF process).

I had it in my mind earlier that a service should return "301 Moved Permanently" for a GET and a "[308 Permanent Redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538#section-3)" for a POST to ensure it is not inappropriately converted to a GET (by something trying to be clever).

Uses of both 301 and 308 seem to be expressed in terms of SHOULDs and SHOULD NOTs rather than MUSTs and MUST NOTs, so it is unclear what "the right thing" is philosphically.

Pragmatically 301 for GET and 308 for POST should work.
308 for GET is not wrong as the [current revision](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7538/?include_text=1) at the time of writing includes an example of 308 being produced in response to a GET.
Now there is a deployment concern that if a client doesn't understand 308 it should treat it like a 300 (rather than a 301 which makes more sense to me) but 308 is now widely understood so the question becomes if or why should you ever use HTTP 301?

If 308 is essentially a bug fix for 301, why isn't 301 officially deprecated in HTTP/1.1? Is there a legitimate use case for converting a POST into a GET for a redirect in ReST or in more generally in HTTP?

For 301 HTTP/1.1 says:

> Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.

Why was that ever a good idea? Is it still valid anywhere?

See also:

- [What's the difference between HTTP 301 and 308 status codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136829/whats-difference-between-http-301-and-308-status-codes)
  which provides good coverage of the difference between 301 and 308 but does not cover this point.
- [How should client of Restful API handle http status 301 redirect upon POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265457/how-should-client-of-restful-api-handle-http-status-301-redirect-upon-post)
- [What's the deal with HTTP status code 308?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144664/whats-the-deal-with-http-status-code-308)

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7538 Generally it's your (design) decision. As in your example there would not be a huge difference. But if you standardize it, you would not need to worry about different cases. Just ask yourself is there a downside using the newer 308 over the old 301? If not use the newer one.

Comment: My hope is that with a well defined protocol like HTTP we can move towards designs where there is one right way to do things. In this case *I* think its 308 (I'm asking 'the internet' why I'm wrong - or possibly right) but if 308 is a bugfix for 301 why didn't the IETF deprecate 301. Does 301 still have a sensible use case separate from 308?

Comment: 308 is not a bug fix. It's rather an extension to secure that the same method will be used (e.g. POST -> POST). How a program or browser reacts to it depends on the implementation. 301 won't deprecate that fast. 308 is there to add another layer of protection/security into the protocol.

Comment: How a client should interpret status codes is mostly covered in the standard so its not implementation dependent. If I returned a 400 for a resource that does not exist instead of 404 I would be wrong. There are systems, including "ReSTish" APIs that do not follow the standard properly. There are may be a few ambiguities (301/308 possibly being one). 301 won't disappear from  implementations overnight. The question is does 308 make it redundant? (if so the right thing is to always use 308 and label 301 as deprecated).

Comment: _Why was that ever a good idea? Is it still valid anywhere?_ If we are lucky enough, we may get some input from [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) who authored the [RFC 7538](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7538) and co-authored the [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) with Fielding.

Answer (score 2):

> If `308` is essentially a bug fix for `301`, why isn't `301` officially deprecated in HTTP/1.1?

No, it's not.

The [RFC 7538](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538), which defines the `308` status code, doesn't invalidate or make `301` obsolete. It just defines *another* status code to fill a gap on the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), which does not define a permanent
variant of status code `307`:

```
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                                           | Permanent | Temporary |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Allows changing the request method from   | 301       | 302       |
| POST to GET                               |           |           |
| Does not allow changing the request       | -         | 307       |
| method from POST to GET                   |           |           |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

In practical terms, I still see `301` being largely used in SEO. And I've seen some HTTP clients that don't recognize `308`.

---

Apart from the RFCs, let's have a look what MDN Web Docs from Mozilla [say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) about `301`:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `301 Moved Permanently` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been definitively moved to the URL given by the Location headers. A browser redirects to this page and search engines update their links to the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said that the 'link-juice' is sent to the new URL).
>
> Even if the specification requires the method (and the body) not to be altered when the redirection is performed, not all user-agents align with it - you can still find this type of bugged software out there. It is therefore recommended to use the `301` code only as a response for `GET` or `HEAD` methods and to use the `308 Permanent Redirect` for `POST` methods instead, as the method change is explicitly prohibited with this status.

Now see what Mozilla [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) about `308`:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `308 Permanent Redirect` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been definitively moved to the URL given by the `Location` headers. A browser redirects to this page and search engines update their links to the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said that the 'link-juice' is sent to the new URL).
>
> The request method and the body will not be altered, whereas `301` may incorrectly sometimes be changed to a `GET` method.
>
> > <sup>**Note:** Some Web applications may use the `308 Permanent Redirect` in a non-standard way and for other purposes. For example, Google Drive uses a `308 Resume Incomplete` response to indicate to the client when an incomplete upload stalled. <sup>[(reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable)</sup></sup>

---

The "historical reasons" in which a user agent may change a request from `POST` to `GET` is explained in an [Eric Lawrence](https://textslashplain.com/about/)'s [post from the IEInternals blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190109001229/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/19/http-methods-and-redirect-status-codes/), dated from 19 August 2011.

The post quotes the definition of the status code `301` from the obsolete [RFC 1945](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), published in May 1996, which defined the HTTP/1.0. The key part from that quote is:

> **Note:** When automatically redirecting a `POST` request after receiving a `301` status code, some existing user agents will erroneously change it into a `GET` request.

Then the author continues:

> [...] those “user agents” referred to in this remark included the popular browsers of the day, including Netscape Navigator and Internet Explorer. Arguably, this behavior is exactly what most websites wanted — after a successful `POST`, send the user to a different URL to show them something else. However, the `POST`-converted-to-`GET` behavior isn’t what the authors of HTTP had intended.

Comment: I can't accept this answer without an explanation for why it is a good idea to "allows changing the request method from POST to GET" as that is the crux of the difference.

Comment: 301 accomplishes the purpose of 302 + permanent. One can imagine a scenario where you need to convert POST to a GET after a form submission to prevent reposts (quite a common scenario), but where the redirection is permanent because the original redirect page is out of date, so you instruct the user agent to update its cache of the final location.